# how to get control over dowload button while viewing pdf in Iframe in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, pdf, iframe

I am using iframes in my Jsp page to display Pdf. It's working perfectly and showing pdf correctly .
Now I need to add an entry to database while downloading or take print using the icons shown in pdf. Is there any way in jquery or javascript to get the click event of that icons, so that i can insert an entry into database?

this is my jsp page,

```
 <div class="m6" >
  <iframe src="test.pdf" width="875" height="95%" id="iframe" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

    </div>
```

I am using servlet(pdfServlet) to display pdf. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The PDF is loaded into an application that is separate from the browser (although embedded in the browser) and there is no communication between the PDF application and the browser. So any events that occur in the PDF are not 'transmitted' to the browser and therefore cannot be captured.

I suggest that you redesign it so that the buttons are in the web page and therefore the click events are detectable.